# Javascript indexOf is not returning result

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a reasonable amount of validation with `indexOf`.

`save()` is an `onclick` attribute for a button.
`saveDirectionsForm` is the `id` of a text input.
`result` is the `id` of an empty paragraph.

This is my code so far. Why nothing is being rendered when I click `save()`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>autoComplete</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="autocomplete.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="masterControls">
    <input name="origin-input" id="origin-input" class="controls" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter an origin location">
    <input name="destination-input" id="destination-input" class="controls" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a destination location">

    <div id="mode-selector" class="controls">
      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-walking">
      <label for="changemode-walking">Walking</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-bicycling" checked="checked">
      <label for="changemode-bicycling">Bicycling</label>

      <!-- <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-transit">
      <label for="changemode-transit">Transit</label> -->

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-driving">
      <label for="changemode-driving">Driving</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;

      <label for="tolls">Avoid Tolls: </label>
      <input id="tolls" type="checkbox" name="tolls" onchange="switchTolls(this)" checked="checked">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;

      <button id="restartMap" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" style="height:80%;top:0;margin-bottom:6px;" onclick="restartMap()" type="button">Restart</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="saveMapAlert" style="display:none;" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button id="saveMapAlertClose" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  <strong>Nice route!</strong> Do you want to save these directions?&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="label label-default" id="yesAlert" onclick="yesAlert()">Yes!</span> <span class="label label-danger" id="noAlert" onclick="noAlert()">No!</span>
  </div>

  <div id="saveDirectionsWrapper" class="col-lg-6" style="display:none;margin-bottom:20px;width:25%;">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required="required" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button id="saveDirectionsForm" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Send!</button>
        <!-- <button id="saveDirectionsForm" onclick="saveDirectionsForm()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button> -->
      </span>
    </div><!-- input-group -->
  </div><!-- col-lg-6 && saveDirectionsWrapper -->

  <div id="saveMapAlert2" style="display:none;" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button id="saveMapAlertClose2" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  <strong>Oh snap!</strong> Blah blah!
  </div>

  <p id="result"></p>

    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="panelWrapper">
      <div id="panel" style="height:100%;width:100%;float:right;"></div>
    </div>

<script>

    function save() {
        var emailString = document.getElementById('saveDirectionsForm').value;
        if (emailString.indexOf("@") > 0) {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "YES";
        }
      };
</script>
```

Comment: what value you check?

Comment: `saveDirectionsForm ` seems like this is a form id, you need to use the email field id

Comment: is the ID of the INPUT field: **saveDirectionsForm**?

Comment: try alert(emailString) prior to the if statement. May be something is wrong in the read value.

Comment: @RemcoK. that is correct.

Comment: You need to provide a real [mcve].

Comment: By including your HTML markup in the question itself, the Q&A session going on in the comments here wouldn't be necessary and you may have already had an answer by now. Consider editing your question to avoid so many repetitive comments!

Comment: `saveDirectionsForm` is the ID of your *"Send!"* button, not a text input. Your *Email Address* input doesn't have an ID.

Comment: "indexOf not returning result" it just returns an integer. Not sure what you're expecting it to return, what is it returning that you're seeing as an issue?

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet I'm expecting it to return "YES". I'm typing @ into the text input, clicking my "Send!" button, and no result is posted into the "result" paragraph.

Comment: why would you think indexof would return yes? you'd need a custom function that reads the indexof, which returns an integer the location of what you're searching on and if it's greater than -1 return YES

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<button id="saveDirectionsForm" onclick="save()"   class="btn btn-default" type="button">Send!</button>
```

This looks weird, you are trying to get the value of a button, it won't work, nothing is wrong with your indexOf method,

```
//you are getting it wrong here 
        var emailString =      document.getElementById('saveDirectionsForm').value;
```

Comment: Apologies for the naming of the button and text input being unorganised. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: You are welcome